# FlowTyped function type inside object

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, flow-typed

I am trying to include function signature inside a type.

```
type validatorAction = {
  validatorFN: function method(str, bool, ...nums) {

  },
  errorKey: string,
  errorMessage: string
}
```

Tried multiple variations but none of them work and the documentation are horrible.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include function implementation in type declaration but specify its (function's) type:

```
type validatorAction = {
  validatorFN: (string, boolean, ...number[]) => boolean,
  errorKey: string,
  errorMessage: string
}
```

And here's version with parameter names:

`validatorFN: (str: string, bool: boolean, ...nums: number[]) => void`

[Documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-function-types)